# Apache Solr search is not displaying indexed result

Tags: java, apache, lucene, solr

Although the data from mysql is properly indexed using dataimport handler but while searching through solr admin it shows zero result, please suggest whats the problem would be[image]

right side display that indexing have been done completely, but not displaying in search results.

and when I used to search "programing" it display

Comment: It could be anything, really; we don't have enough information. How do you know the data is properly indexed if you can't find it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Luke to examine your index contents and verify that you have indexed your data correctly. http://www.getopt.org/luke/

There's also a debugging tab in Solr for queries to determine whether or not your query would actually match given the way that you have setup your tokenizers.